# Not able to record sound in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, audio-recording, system-sounds

I run Ubuntu 10.04. I can hear sound from my PC, but I can't record any sound. I have checked all the preliminary tests by checking the sound-systems preferences & alsamixer switches to make the system working, but could not solve the problem.

I have tried quite a few configurations based on web searches, but unfortunately, that did not help me.

Can you please help me to solve this sound recording problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and add everything you've tried so the community doesn't suggest you things you already know. Please also include your hardware specifications.

Comment: Sound card support in Linux is spotty. Is your sound card supported by that version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Sound card onboard or PCI? What software are you using to record?